# margin-bottom working differently in front page

Tags: css

I have the following css, the margin values are working in all menu pages the same but it is different only in front page that is "The Landmark" contents at right side

```
h1.componentheading, .componentheading, #ja-component h2 {
    padding: 5px 0 15px;
    margin: 15px 0 10px;
    /*background: url(../images/hdot.gif) repeat-x bottom;*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F3A831;
    color: #F3A831;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

When I replace it to `margin: 15px 0 0;` it works perfectly. But actually I want to give this margin value of 10px to all pages heading. Please anyone find this reason.

[test page](http://nepotech.com/thelandmark/index.php)

I'm using joomla template.

**Screen Shot**

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I can't spot any difference.

Comment: `The Landmark` is encapsulated in 13 div and it's not even a heading or a paragraph? Wow. Also you've duplicated `id` and missing `alt` attributes according to http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @zeroflagL place your finger at paragraph of "The Landmark" and click to another menu then you'll see the difference

Comment: Nothing. What browser do you use? can you add screenshots or at least describe the difference you are experiencing?

Comment: Ok please wait I'm attaching a screenshot

Comment: I'm testing it in firefox 18. There is about 10px different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is different on the 'landmarks' page:

```
    <h2>OUR GEMS</h2>
    <p>We call them Banquet Halls, but they are so ...</p>
```

versus

The Landmark

```
  <table class="blog" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <div>     
            <div class="contentpaneopen">
              <div class="article-content">
                <p>A warm welcome to the <strong>Landmark Hotel</strong>, ...
```

In the first snippet you are experiencing [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

The second snippet is just a mess (tabels for layout, no headings, way to much markup, ...), and there is no margin collapse at work here.

You can't expect the same result if your markup is that different.

I would advise you to fix your markup (make it look like the first snippet) and your look will be consistent

**edit:**
If you insist on keeping the table, you could add a negative margin to it to mimic the margin collapse. Something like this:

```
.componentheading + table.blog {
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: I'm using joomla template so I couldn't change the markup but why it's same in grand eateris

Comment: If so, you mean this the table is causing to set margin of 10px

Comment: the table is making the margins not collapse. You realy should try to get rid of that table, template are not, tables should only be used for tabular data, not for layout.

Comment: Is there no way to do without removing table?

Comment: yes, , set a negative margin top on the table, `margin-top: -10px;`, all though I would advise against this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32638/discussion-between-c-link-and-petervr)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the reason that the spacing is being produced is because you have the .article-content div contained inside a table that has the class "blog" attached to it.

You have a lot of css styling that points to padding being applied to tables throughout your website.

Comment: why is this for front page only. if so it should do as in other pages

Comment: For all of your other pages, <div class="article-content"> is not wrapped inside a table. The front page is the only one that I can see that it is. Try remove this -->> <table class="blog" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">...